# How to escape output data?

Tags: magento-1, template, security

Is there a built-in Magento helper to escape outputted template data to prevent XSS?

Or should I just use the PHP [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) functions?

Comment: If you are looking for Magento 2 please refer to https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/156368/243

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are several helper method depending on the context. All are defined in `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract` but also in `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`, so you can use them with `$this->...()` in every template:

- `escapeHtml()`: It actually leverages `htmlspecialchars` with the recommended parameters to escape HTML: `$result = htmlspecialchars($result, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);` - additionally you can specify a whitelist of allowed tags and call the method on an array to escape all elements at once. **Use this for any inline text.**
- `quoteEscape()`: a simpler version without whitelist and array processing but this one escapes single quotes as well as double quotes, useful for **text within a HTML attribute**.
- `jsQuoteEscape()`: this one escapes single quotes with a backslash. It is used to escape string literals in JavaScript. But this is **not secure**. (Example by @Xorax: `'test\\\'+alert("powned");//'`). Additional escaping of backslashes is necessary. **Use `quoteEscape()` instead!**
- `escapeUrl()`: I don't know why this method exists, it's *not* URL encoding strings, it's just plain old `htmlspecialchars()` without any parameter. **Don't use it. Ever.**

  ```
  /**
   * Escape html entities in url
   *
   * @param string $data
   * @return string
   */
  public function escapeUrl($data)
  {
      return htmlspecialchars($data);
  }
  ```
- On a related note, there is `urlEncode()` which also not applies URL encoding, but base64 instead... **Don't use it, if you don't know exactly what you need.**

  ```
  /**
   *  base64_encode() for URLs encoding
   *
   *  @param    string $url
   *  @return   string
   */
  public function urlEncode($url)
  {
      return strtr(base64_encode($url), '+/=', '-_,');
  }
  ```

Yes, the naming is inconsistent. Once all those method names were following the scheme `somethingEscape()` but then somebody decided to deprecate `htmlEscape()` and `urlEscape()` in favor of the new methods and forgot about `quoteEscape()` and `jsQuoteEscape()`.

Comment: jsQuoteEscape is it really secure ? Look like str_replace($quote, '\\'.$quote, ...) does not do the job... https://gist.github.com/xxorax/1c9653fd59785085f96d4f676bc64ee2

Comment: @Xorax very good point. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 21):

### Just translate it

You should always be using the standard translate function

**In a block instance**

```
<?php echo $this->__('Text goes here'); ?>
```

**Anywhere else**

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->__('Text goes here'); ?>
```

And use it the same way you would use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) with PHP

Eg.

```
<?php $foo = 'rocks'; ?>
<?php echo $this->__('Sonassi %s', $foo); ?>
```

### Or escape it

**In a block instance**

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml('HTML goes here'); ?>
```

**Anywhere else**

Using `Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php`

```
escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags = null)
```

Eg.

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml('HTML goes here'); ?>
```

Comment: Important note: `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::htmlEscape()` is deprecated as of Magento v 1.4.0.0-rc1 and `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::escapeHtml()` should be used instead.

Comment: Another important note: **Translation does not escape anything**. Try it out: `$this->__('Hello %s', '<script>alert("XSS!")</script>')`.

Answer (score 3):

Classes `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` and `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract` both use the same function `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract::escapeHtml` and it's implementation internaly uses PHP htmlspecialchars function besides implementing some aditional logic for arrays with HTML content.

The function can be accessed in all block and helper classes through $this and since the function is public you can use it through Mage::helper( 'core' ), or some other helper class, everywhere else.

Answer (score -1):

For spanish convert:

```
$value = str_replace(array("&lt;", "&gt;"), array("<", ">"), htmlspecialchars("Lorem ipsum &gt;", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8", false));
```