# Basic echo in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I see something like the below in magento

```
<?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?>
```

Why can't I simply use

```
<?php echo "Required Fields" ?>
```

The output seems to be the same in both cases. 
What is the function of the $this->__ . I see this usage in a lot of places and would like to clear any misunderstanding I may be having.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main difference is that this:

```
<?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?>
```

Allows for front end translations through a CSV file or through the Admin Panel  (Configuration -> Developer -> Translate Inline)

Where as:

```
<?php echo "Required Fields" ?>
```

Will not allow you to use the translation features.

Comment: Best practice is to use the `$this->__('echo text here')` - your site is English now but maybe down the line it will require additional languages. The code you posted gets the username of a logged in user.

Comment: Thanks - that helps. I tried searching for the nature of escapeHtml ? What exactly is this doing ? why couldn't I simply have done $this->getUsername().

Comment: Post a new question :)

Comment: Matter of time before someone said that - I was asking for it :)

Comment: Even if your site is only in English, to might want to change texts per theme or store without having to change them in all templates. Regarding `escapeHtml()`: You want to be sure that it also works if the translation has funny characters. See: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/569/how-to-escape-output-data

Comment: Escaping HTML is for security (e.g. protecting against injection attacks) whereas __('xxx') is for translating static strings into other languages (the string xxx is the key in the CSV file).